# Netty. How to share object between handlers?

Tags: netty

Yo guys. In my pipeline are 3 handlers:

1. ConnectionHandler
2. FrameHandler
3. PacketHandler

In ConnectionHandler I have created a Session object. I need only 1 Session object for each client, that's why I initialize it in ConnectionHandler, because channelActive method called only 1 time for each client.
I wish to pass that Session into PacketHandler.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 11):

You can use Channel.attr(...).set(...) and Channel.attr(...).get(...) for this kind of stuff. Check the javadocs.

So something like this:

```
public static AttibuteKey<String> MY_KEY = AttributeKey.valueOf("MY_KEY");
public final class ConnectHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHanderContext ctx) {
        ctx.channel().attr(MY_KEY).set("Whatever");
    }
}

public final class NextHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) {
        String value = ctx.channel().attr(MY_KEY).get();
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, actually I already try it, but I did not understand how it's works, I doing it in ConnectionHandler        ctx.attr(new AttributeKey<Session>("session")).set(session); but how to GET this data in PacketHandler I don't realize

Comment: See my edited response... should help you to get started

Comment: Hehe. Actually I have already solved that problem, and did it just like in your post. Seems must to be only 1 instance of AttributeKey.